angular token save in localstorage give me undefined
i want save the token and the response object have the token but i cant save it in the localstorage value of the token give me undefined
this the login function
  login() {
    this.errorMsg = [];
    this.authService
      .authenticate({
        body: this.authRequest,
      })
      .subscribe({
        next: (res) => {
          this.tokenService.token = res.token as string;
          console.log(res.token);
          
          // this.router.navigate(['books']);
        },
        error: (err) => {
          console.log(err);
          if (err.error.validationErrors) {
            this.errorMsg = err.error.validationErrors;
          } else {
            this.errorMsg.push(err.error.error);
          }
        },
      });
  }

this is the token service class
export class TokenService {
  
  set token(token: string) {
      localStorage.setItem('token', token);
  }

  get token() {
    return localStorage.getItem('token') as string;
  }
}



how are you initializing TokenService do you have providedIn; 'root'? or are you adding in providers array, if so, please share how you are adding!

Can you give us more context, because with your actual code, we can only say that your res doesn't contains your token

@Neo share the lines above export class TokenService {

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root',
}) evrything is ok but i dont know why the token give me undefiend the autocomplete suggest it , and token when i console.log(res.token) also undefiend

@Neo just try console.log(res), replace to auth token contents with some junk values the token since its contains sensitive data and update on the question, since token is undefined, you are accessing the wrong property, access the property of the API call, check the network tab! or try debugging
